# Textarea handling with meteor

Tags: meteor, textarea

I'm back with a really stupid question this time.

I have a text area in my html, and want to get its value on a Meteor event.

Like for many of my element, i do :

```
var foo = tmpl.find('#myID').value;
```

But for my text area, nothing I tried worked.

I tried :

```
var foo = tmpl.find('#myID').value;
var foo = tmpl.find('#myID').val();
var foo = tmpl.find('#myID').text;
var foo = tmpl.find('#myID').html;
var foo = tmpl.find('#myID').innerHTML;
```

Without a single result other than a recusive with innerHTML.

Wtf am i doing wrong? I used to do one of the two first when i was working on ancient project, without meteor.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use jQuery like this: `$('#myID').val()`. Using `find` here doesn't really make sense since ids must be unique.

Comment: I've tested that one too :/

Comment: Do you have the jquery package added?  `meteor add jquery`

Comment: @DavidPanart Did you try it on the browser console? I wonder if it's an issue of when/how the code is being executed.

Comment: Yes I did. The only thing working seems to be console.log($('#update-bio').val());

But a new assignment with  .value = "something" does not work :/

Comment: I'm the stupidiest JS dev ever *-*

I forgot to call the {{bio}} to display the value --'